# how to retrieve whole row through session after user log in

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to retrieve whole row of data from database when a specific user log in. and show it in my view of profile.

this is my **Controller** already assigned it a Session variable on ID, I now want to retrieve data from database through this U_ID.

```
public ActionResult Index(Account_Details log)
    {

        var obj = db.Account_Details.Where(u => u.Name.Equals(log.Name) && u.Password.Equals(log.Password)).FirstOrDefault();

        if (obj != null)
        {

            Session["loginid"] = obj.U_ID;
            Session["name"] = obj.Name;
            return RedirectToAction("Welcome");
        }

        else
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

this is my Model where I've assigned a foreign key to Basic_Detail table in database. So, that I can get Basic_Detail row of data through U_ID.

```
public partial class Account_Details
{
    public Account_Details()
    {
        this.Basic_Details = new HashSet<Basic_Details>();
    }

    public int U_ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [MinAge]
    public string DOB { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Basic_Details> Basic_Details { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: you can use `db.Account_Details.include(x => x.Basic_Details).Where(u => u.Name.Equals(log.Name) && u.Password.Equals(log.Password)).FirstOrDefault();`  to get the navigational property of basic_detail table

Comment: @Niladri, thanks for your response pal, though it seems like you didn't get the question properly. in simple words, let me rephrase my question. "I need whole data of a logged in user through Session"

Comment: `this is my Model where I've assigned a foreign key to Basic_Detail table in database. So, that I can get Basic_Detail row of data through U_ID.` this is what is done by the above query,you don't need to query again .

Comment: The `obj` you're saving in the session already contains everything you need, you just have to write some code to display it in your page. Entity framework will automatically return the related Basic_Details records (the ones linked by foreign key to your U_ID) already in the object when you make your query. So you just need to access those items within your Account_Details object. Since there's a foreign key relationship, and Account_Details.Basic_Details is a list, you'll probably need to use a loop to display them all.

Comment: Anyone up to solve my problem. it's been viewed 49 times yet no one showed up with a proper reply.

Comment: We've given you all the clues you need. Have you tried to use the suggestions? Don't you understand what we're telling you?  If the suggestions don't help then you need to explain the question better.

Comment: You said, entity will display all the related data, you've bound through foreign key. while it isn't the case, cause i've bound two tables and compared their "ID". I now want this "User logged in, then retrieve the information of the same ID from different table through session".